# Grouping by multiple columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a CSV file which has the following data:-

```
index,fromUserId,toUserId,communicationTypeId,communicationStatusId,createdOn
5,71124481.0,24544531.0,100003279.0,100003280.0,1617461621712.0
6,71124481.0,73922852.0,100003279.0,100003280.0,1617461694769.0
7,71124481.0,74019471.0,100003279.0,100003280.0,1617461717863.0
8,71124481.0,73712049.0,100003279.0,100003280.0,1617461763337.0
9,71124481.0,69843616.0,100003279.0,100003280.0,1617461872580.0
10,71124481.0,72062442.0,100003279.0,100003280.0,1617462041742.0
11,71124481.0,24544531.0,100003276.0,100003282.0,1617462090224.0
12,71124481.0,74022580.0,100003279.0,100003280.0,1617462424555.0
13,71124481.0,74000295.0,100003279.0,100003280.0,1617632346611.0
14,71124481.0,74000295.0,100003276.0,100003281.0,1617632348469.0
```

I want to group this by 'fromUserId' and 'toUserId'. Hence, my result set would be something like this:-

```
fromUserId,toUserId,[(index,communicationTypeId,communicationStatusId,createdOn)]

71124481.0,24544531.0,[(5,100003279.0,100003280.0,1617461621712.0)]
71124481.0,73922852.0,[(6,100003279.0,100003280.0,1617461694769.0)]
71124481.0,74019471.0,[(7,100003279.0,100003280.0,1617461717863.0)]
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

71124481.0,74000295.0,[(13,100003279.0,100003280.0,1617632346611.0), (14,100003276.0,100003281.0,1617632348469.0)]
```

Can someone help me out in how to achieve this? I shall be grateful! Thank you!

Comment: `df.groupby(['fromUserId','toUserId']).agg(list)`

Answer (score 1):

As seen from your expected result, the resulting list is actually a **list of tuple(s)**, instead of purely a list of items, you can approach as follows:

Firstly, *for each row*, make a tuple with elements from the selected columns using [`.apply(tuple)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on `axis=1`, then group by the 2 columns `fromUserId` and `toUserId` by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate the tuple(s) in each group into a list by [`.agg(list)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html), as follows:

```
df_out = (df[['index', 'communicationTypeId', 'communicationStatusId', 'createdOn']]
             .apply(tuple, axis=1)
             .groupby([df['fromUserId'], df['toUserId']], sort=False)
             .agg(list)
             .reset_index(name='[(index,communicationTypeId,communicationStatusId,createdOn)]')
         )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

   fromUserId    toUserId                                           [(index,communicationTypeId,communicationStatusId,createdOn)]
0  71124481.0  24544531.0   [(5.0, 100003279.0, 100003280.0, 1617461621712.0), (11.0, 100003276.0, 100003282.0, 1617462090224.0)]
1  71124481.0  73922852.0                                                      [(6.0, 100003279.0, 100003280.0, 1617461694769.0)]
2  71124481.0  74019471.0                                                      [(7.0, 100003279.0, 100003280.0, 1617461717863.0)]
3  71124481.0  73712049.0                                                      [(8.0, 100003279.0, 100003280.0, 1617461763337.0)]
4  71124481.0  69843616.0                                                      [(9.0, 100003279.0, 100003280.0, 1617461872580.0)]
5  71124481.0  72062442.0                                                     [(10.0, 100003279.0, 100003280.0, 1617462041742.0)]
6  71124481.0  74022580.0                                                     [(12.0, 100003279.0, 100003280.0, 1617462424555.0)]
7  71124481.0  74000295.0  [(13.0, 100003279.0, 100003280.0, 1617632346611.0), (14.0, 100003276.0, 100003281.0, 1617632348469.0)]
```